# Journal of Biblical Accuracy

Tags: discussion

This is the [Journal of Biblical Accuracy](http://www.jba.gr/aboutus.htm). Despite its formal erudite title, I am not sure if this is a trustworthy source for me to use here, because it's really a "magazine", not a real peer-reviewed academic journal on Biblical Studies, Religious Studies, or Theology. The webpage to which I linked has a link that lists a lot of universities and colleges in various countries. There are Bible colleges as well as Lutheran universities. The website itself says it's a "non-denominational" source, which may mask denominational differences. How should I treat this source? Should I treat this source as its own separate denomination with its own set of beliefs? Should I treat this source as an independent Christian outlet? I really wish I could know the denomination, because if I don't, then I can't use this source to answer a denomination-based truth question on the Stack Exchange or a hermeneutics question on the C.SE. The articles all seem to be written by one person too, so it's hardly an academic journal - so really, do I just have to know this guy's theological background and adequately represent his background?

Comment: It looks like a personal web page. The few pages I looked at weren't particularly deep. I'm not sure why you'd want to reference it. Still if there was a relevant page, you could quote from it to answer questions like "does anyone think x?" There may be info in there to answer historical or cultural questions too.

Answer (score 3):

From the home page:

> This magazine is a non-denominational Christian magazine whose aim is
>   to teach the Word of God and serve through this way the one body of
>   Christ. This magazine is not connected or sponsored (in money or any
>   other way) by anybody. It is simply the sincere effort of the author
>   to participate in my role in building up my brothers and sisters
>   through teaching of the Word of God. Everything in this magazine is
>   for free.

As a source for referencing, it's just some guy's work.  It's no better than a personal blog by some random Joe off the street.  It's certainly not in the same sanding as a denomination, and not a suitable source.

However, if there are articles in there that cite other references, feel free to follow those and use the cited references.

Comment: So, a denomination actually takes precedence over an individual?

Comment: @DoubleU If you ask something about a denomination, then of course!? Most of the time we are interested here in official doctrine of some denomination, not personal interpretation, as far as I understood the site. That doesn't mean (IMHO) that an individual has nothing useful to add to a discussion, though.

Comment: Actually, [I think it can be a suitable source in some circumstances.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4424/3961)

Answer (score 2):

David answered well, but in some circumstances it can be a suitable source. Biblical basis questions are exactly the kind of question that can use this as a source.

A question asks for the biblical basis of a particular belief. You go ahead and provide that. Then, naturally, you need to prove that some people do indeed use the bible in this way to support this belief. If this site has an article about that and it matches what you've given then feel free to use it as a source in this circumstance.